# Using Grid should we need to mention the url of each node in each test case

Tags: testing, selenium, testng

how to mention on which node, which test case should be executed.
For example:
suppose on system with IP a1, I have started grid HUB
and have registered b1, b2, b3 to the hub a1.

Now if I have a class with tests `tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4, tc5` etc..,
**How should I inititalise the driver in each test case?**

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://**a1:port/wd/hub**"));
```

In all the test cases and it in turn will tie up the test case to the nodes

(Or)

Need to mention the node url on which we want to execute test case in each test case.

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://b1:port/wd/hub"));
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://b2:port/wd/hub"));
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://b3:port/wd/hub"));
```

Comment: So your question is how can you run your test cases on every node? Or how can you set up that on which node gets your test cases run?

Comment: My question is how to setup "on which node which test case should execute". If Grid will handle that then is there any way to find out  "on which node which test case **got execute**" .

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to specify the URL or or instance hostname of any of the Nodes.  Just point your tests at the Grid hub and it knows how to route to any of the attached nodes depending on the browser Capabilities that you send it.

These URLs may help you understand:

```
http://hub:4444/admin/
http://node1:5555/extra/NodeLog
http://node2:5555/extra/NodeLog
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. "http://hub:4444/admin/" do you mean "http://localhost:4444/admin/" . If so i got the below info                                       You are using grid 2.45.0
Find help on the official selenium wiki : more help here
default monitoring page : console

Comment: Actually I wanted to know which is the best way to run the tests in parallel. As per my understanding, I found using Selenium Grid with Test Ng and schedule it using Jenkins would help me out. My query is If suppose I have say 1000 different test in say 100 classes. Now should I have to initialise the [RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://hubIP:port/wd/hub"));]  in all the tests . and hub will take care on which of the node it will run?

Comment: Is there any way to get on which node which tests got executed. awaiting your reply. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You just have to init your RemoteWebDriver and register it on the hub, and also set up the DesiredCapabilites. According to that the hub will decide that on which node get your test done. For example:

If you register the following node with the following settings:

```
{
    "capabilities":[
        {
            "platform":"VISTA",
            "browserName":"chrome",
            "version":"30",
            "maxInstances":1,
            "seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver"
        }
    ],
    "configuration":{
        "port":5555,
        "host":"localhost",
        "register":true,
        "hubHost":"localhost",
        "hubPort":4444,
        "maxSession":1,

    }
}
```

and if you register the following RemoteWebDriver:

```
WebDriver driver;
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
dc.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.VISTA);
dc.setVersion("30");
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), dc);
```

Then your code will run on that node in that browser.

If you have more node which can provide the same browser (same platform, same browser, same browserversion), then the hub will check that which node is the the least overloaded, and which node can provide a free instance of the browser.

If you want to run your test on a specific computer then your node have to get labeled. The easiest solution is to use the "applicationName" capability, or you can create custom capability matcher. Here is a short example what I wrote under another question: [Selenium Grid and RemoteWebDriver..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595466/selenium-grid-and-remotewebdriver/29622536#29622536)